# "I'm not X, am I?" vs. "I'm not X, do I?"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, auxiliary-verbs, question-tags

Which of the following is correct or better? Can they both be used?

> - I'm not making any sense, am I?
> - I'm not making any sense, do I?

Comment: I just wanted to point out to the phrase "Aren't I?" but it only fits contexts like "I am making sense, aren't I?" and is a synonym to "am I not?".

Answer (score 5):

In a question tag, if there is an auxiliary verb in the sentence, you always use it. Otherwise you use the appropriate form of the verb *do*.

> I'm not making any sense, am I?

There are a few exceptions. One is the quasi-modal *used to*, which used to take *usedn't*, but doesn't any more.

> You used to work here, didn't you?
>   *You used to work here, usedn't you?

Answer (score 2):

Use

> I'm not making any sense, am I?
>
> I don't make any sense, do I?

Do not use

> *I'm not making any sense, do I?
>
> *I don't make any sense, am I?

Comment: It's worth noting that "I'm not making any sense" and "I don't make any sense" are not identical in meaning.  "I'm not making any sense" refers to the present, or immediate past; it would usually mean "the last remark I made was nonsensical".  In comparison, "I don't make any sense" suggests that I make a habit of not making sense; there's more than just one incident.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is **I'm not making any sense, am I?** The implied predicate of *am I?* is *am making*, while the implied predicate of the *do I?* is *do making*, which is incorrect.

---

Think of it this way. The sentences really almost say two things:

> I'm not making any sense. Am I not making any sense?
>
> I'm not making any sense. Do I not making any sense?

If you reword the last sentence of each example (for clarity's sake; you'd never actually say it like this):

> I am not making any sense.
>
> I do not making any sense.